# A lot of requests in same moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I want scrape a lot of pages (350/1500) and when i try to make function where is request and scrape using cheerio and another function using loop for all links (350/1500) but only get "current div" (body) from of the first five - another is empty or 0. How can I write a function that waits for the page to load and be ready to download and extract the item?

Comment: Use `async await` to wait for the request to load the data and an async functions for scrapping.

Comment: @GauravSharma can you give me a example function using 'async await'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is very high level because I don't know your use case

```
const urls = []; // populate it with page urls
async function start() {
  try {
    for(const url of urls) {
      const html = await getPageHtml(URL);
      const scrappedData = await getScrappedData(HTML);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

async getPageHtml(url) {
  // use request library promised version for fetching data and await for the response
}

async getScrappedData(html) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // call resolve with data like this
    resolve(data)
    // if faced any error then call reject like this
    reject(err)
  })
}

start()
```

Comment: try-catch will handle it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Just added. Thanks :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ATxjtch6 i do this. and when loop is running then giving me a weird error

Comment: @KamilW It is running. Can you share that error? It would help in debugging.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ui9rts (up is all body from web i think)

Comment: @KamilW Add your for..of loop inside an async function as I did in the answer. See start() function

Comment: Oh in red code i saw 'operation blocked. your request has been blocked becouse you send too much similar request'... so how i can make a hmm 300ms waiting for next request?

Comment: Use setTimeout for 300 ms delay

Comment: i'm used setTimeout in insade a loop and my console.log = undefined + giving all body site with request blocked.. i dont know how to solve it..

Comment: your request is getting blocked by the website you are hitting? update your Pastebin code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j08wKibX (i tried set setTimeout on 1s)

Comment: you are still firing all request at the same time at 1st second. change 1000ms to 1000*j ms.

Comment: and change var j to let j

Comment: seems it work but why if users[] have more than 1 record this for checking all for only one player and x2? i get 2x. loot_res nick 792 , x2  e.t.c

Comment: Do upvote and mark it answer if you think it solves your problem. That may be some logical error. use debugger or console.log

Comment: Ok for 1 user and 7 pages it working but when is 200 users and 7 pages its crashing (request block) i mean: one second: 1 request in same time, two seconds: 2 request.... 5 seconds = 5 request and crashing :/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bxp9HneM - i want to this function who's looping for all users doing that: 1 user (7 pages - each with an interval of 200 ms) and the user 200 ms each after himself. Now the queries overlap and at some point the query is blocked because there are more than 5 of them at once

Comment: instead of `300*( j + i )` write `300*( j + i * type_scopes.length )`